# MySQL Sorting bad performance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I see the following (simplified) query appearing in my slow-log mysql file, it's by a search engine crawler that crawls all pages from a paginated website.

```
select * from listing 
where 
   active=1 
   and approved=1 
   and deleted=0 
   and enabled=1 
order by 
   full_listing desc,  
   picture_count*rating/rating_count desc, 
   rating desc 
limit 21230, 10;
```

I'm surprised it takes over 8 seconds to process on a table of only 60,000 records.

The explain plan looks like this

```
1   SIMPLE  listing0_   index_merge listing_active,listing_approved,listing_enabled,listing_deleted,sort_index  listing_active,listing_approved,listing_enabled,listing_deleted 1,1,1,1     3102    Using intersect(listing_active,listing_approved,listing_enabled,listing_deleted); Using where; Using filesort
```

What index can I create in order to improve its performance?

table structure:

```
'CREATE TABLE `listing` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `approved` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `denied` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `full_listing` bit(1) DEFAULT b''0'',
  `public_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `picture_count` int(11) DEFAULT ''0'',
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedBy` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `listing_public_id` (`public_id`),
  KEY `FKB4DC521D9306A80C` (`account_id`),
  KEY `FKB4DC522D7A66E1A8` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `listing_active` (`active`),
  KEY `listing_approved` (`approved`),
  KEY `listing_enabled` (`enabled`),
  KEY `listing_deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `listing_picture_count` (`picture_count`),
  KEY `listing_rating` (`rating`),
  KEY `listing_rating_count` (`rating_count`),
  KEY `listing_full_listing` (`full_listing`),
  CONSTRAINT `listing_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listing_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `domain` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59512 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `full_listing`? What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE listing` look like?

Answer (score 1):

`Using filesort`  could be a cause. What are the index's ? Personally i would use bitshifts for what you are doing for for example column status contains an int

with the right hand bits as this

0000
Active | Approved | Deleted | enabled

so in your example I would have `where status = 1011`
or `status = 11` (when the bits are converted back in to ints)

Then you only have 1 index with all combinations (using 0 and 1 can sometimes make mysql ignore the index)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think bitmasks can't be indexed with MySQL?

Comment: leave it as an int. so the situation you describe above is number 11. Deleted would be (assuming just the deleted flag is 1) equal to 2. Do that logic on the application side. so the query http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html should help with the application logic side. It makes for very readable code also. Int fields are indexable

Comment: I think that's a great idea.  but I'm having performance issues in production right now, is there anything I can do in terms of indexes to improve the query?  This is in fact a part of a query, i left out the joins. (eg. a join on the account table, on account_id = account.id, in order to do some additional bit checks, like account.active = 1)